# Is there a Microsoft version of SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 for x64?

Tags: bids

I'm trying to install the following tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

It's BIDS for Visual Stuido 2012.

At the moment, the only available download on this page is the x86 version, which is erroring due to the following failed condition: "The CPU architecture of the installing feature(s) matches the specified instance."

I noticed on the above download URL, x64 was listed as supported, but there's no download for the x64 version of this file. Anyone advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it by opting to install a new instance rather than augment an existing sql server within the installer.